# Neo4j integrate relationship matrix from csv with millions of relationships fast

Tags: csv, matrix, neo4j, relationship, neo4j-apoc

I am integrating a huge csv file into my neo4j database.
This csv is a matrix of relationships whereas the first row represents one type of nodes (cells ("model_id") and the first column represents the other type of node (genes ("gene_id"). I want to create a relationship for each cell so that the value in the corresponding cell is a property of the relationship in neo4j.
The csv has this structure:
gene_id,     cell1, cell2, cell3
gene1, value, value, value
gene2, value, value, value
gene3, value, value, value

For the gene1 want and gene 2 I want to create a relationship (gene1:Gene{gene_id:"gene1")-[r:READCOUNT{value:value}]->(cell1:Cell{model_id:"cell1"})

In my case I already created the cell and gene nodes beforehand and creating the relationships takes very long (37000 genes and 1200 cells --> 1,200*3,700=44,400,000). Is there a way to boost this insertion?
My Query looks like this right now:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('

CALL apoc.load.csv("rna.csv",{sep:";"}) yield map as line 
return line
','
WITH line
MATCH (c:CellLine)
WITH c,line
SKIP 1 
MATCH (g:Gene ) WHERE g.gene_id=line["gene_id"]
UNWIND c as x
Create (x)-[e:READCOUNT{value:line[x.model_id]}]->(g)

  ', {batchSize:1, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the gene_id?

Comment: No, the gene_id is not corresponding to the line, some gene_ids are missing. In general the gene_id property looks like this : prefix+number
where the prefix is the same for all genes but the numbers are not continous.

Comment: You use the gene_id for matching, so it would make sense to have a Neo4j index on it